# Is there a way to scale ViewBoxes such that their contents displayed is uniform across ALL viewboxes being displayed in a control?

Tags: c#, wpf, scaling, viewbox

I use the ViewBox control with the TextBlock control to display most of the text that exists in applications with which I work.

The problem that I encounter is that in most cases, the effect is not great. Some text can be much larger than other text, and this is not ideal. I can't just specify a font across all text either since I don't know the users hardware, and a ViewBox seems the ideal solution except for this one problem.

I've created a `Behavior<Panel>` class to manage this issue and it works well enough most of the time... except for now. This leads me to believe that my approach is not ideal, and I was hoping that someone could point me in a more "correct" direction.

I'm using an `ItemsControl` to display some information, which is where the problem comes in -

In compliance with the requisite "[Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" requirements...

This is the window code -

```
<Window
    x:Class="ViewboxScaling.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ViewboxScaling"
    mc:Ignorable="d" Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemSource, Source={x:Static Application.Current}}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="2">
                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <local:ViewBoxScalingBehavior />
                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </UniformGrid>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Viewbox Margin="5,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
            </Viewbox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

This is the behavior class -

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace ViewboxScaling {
    class ViewBoxScalingBehavior : Behavior<Panel> {
        protected override void OnAttached( ) {
            //Initially, I would only use the Loaded event.
            this.AssociatedObject.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(
                ( S, E ) => this._bindViewBoxHeight( ) );
            //However, because of my current use case, I need to know
            //whenever the panel has new children added to it.
            this.AssociatedObject.LayoutUpdated += new EventHandler(
                ( S, E ) => this._bindViewBoxHeight( ) );
            base.OnAttached( );
        }

        private void _bindViewBoxHeight( ) {
            List<Viewbox> boxes =
                FindVisualChildren<Viewbox>(
                    this.AssociatedObject ).Where(
                    vb => vb.ActualHeight > 0 &&
                    vb.Child is FrameworkElement ).ToList( );

            foreach ( Viewbox VB in boxes ) {
                //Clear bindings and re-set values.
                BindingOperations.ClearBinding(
                    VB, FrameworkElement.HeightProperty );
                BindingOperations.ClearBinding(
                    VB, FrameworkElement.WidthProperty );
                VB.Height = double.NaN;
                VB.Width = double.NaN;
            }

            Viewbox
                heightSource = boxes.MinBy( vb => vb.ActualHeight ),
                widthSource = boxes.MinBy( vb => vb.ActualWidth );
            Binding
                heightBinding = new Binding( "ActualHeight" ) { Source = heightSource },
                widthBinding = new Binding( "ActualWidth" ) { Source = widthSource };

            foreach ( Viewbox vb in boxes.Where( box => box != heightSource ) )
                BindingOperations.SetBinding(
                    vb, FrameworkElement.HeightProperty, heightBinding );

            foreach ( Viewbox vb in boxes.Where( box => box != widthSource ) )
                BindingOperations.SetBinding(
                    vb, FrameworkElement.WidthProperty, widthBinding );
        }

        public static List<T> FindVisualChildren<T>( DependencyObject o )
            where T : DependencyObject {
            List<T> Children = new List<T>( );
            for ( int x = 0; x < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount( o ); x++ ) {
                var o2 = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild( o, x );
                if ( o2 != null ) {
                    if ( o2 is T )
                        Children.Add( ( T )o2 );
                    Children.AddRange( FindVisualChildren<T>( o2 ) );
                }
            }
            return Children;
        }

        public static T FindUpVisualTree<T>( DependencyObject initial ) 
            where T : DependencyObject {
            DependencyObject current = initial;
            while ( current != null && current.GetType( ) != typeof( T ) )
                current = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent( current );
            return current as T;
        }
    }

    static class VBSExtensions {
        public static T MinBy<T, U>( this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, U> selector )
            where U : IComparable<U> {
            if ( source == null ) throw new ArgumentNullException( "source" );
            bool first = true;
            T minObj = default(T);
            U minKey = default(U);
            foreach ( var item in source ) {
                if ( first ) {
                    minObj = item;
                    minKey = selector( minObj );
                    first = false;
                } else {
                    U currentKey = selector( item );
                    if ( currentKey.CompareTo( minKey ) < 0 ) {
                        minKey = currentKey;
                        minObj = item;
                    }
                }
            }

            return minObj;
        }
    }
}
```

The code in the extension class is to search the Panel for any `ViewBox` objects, as well as any `ViewBox` elements within the `Panel`s children, and their children, and so on and so forth... The `MinBy` method is for finding the smallest ViewBox either by height or by width, since those are the items which will serve as the sources for the width and the height of every other view box.

This is the code for `App.xaml` :

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace ViewboxScaling {
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application, INotifyPropertyChanged {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private readonly string[] _itemSource = new string[] {
            "Text", "Slightly Longer Text"
        };
        public string[ ] ItemSource {
            get { return this._itemSource; }
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the application, the text flits around in what I can only assume is some sort of loop ( or repeated-calls to `LayoutUpdated` ). So, as I said - if there were some other, more reliable method for knowing when a Panel had children added ( or removed ) to ( or from ) it, that would make this much easier. This is the big issue, but I had to lay everything out here.

Comment: IMO using ViewBoxes for all texts is the wrong approach in the first place. An application with different "font sizes" in each text element looks dilettantish. Better choose an appropriate layout and a fixed overall font size at application startup.

Comment: @Clemens The problem is that having a static font size doesn't do well when the control occupies the entire window, the size of which is not static. I can't just say "Okay, font size 12. that's fine" because if the window is occupied by only a few text blocks ( which will be the case ), then there will be a truckload of dead space. Not ideal.

Comment: And you can't put the whole control in a single Viewbox? Anyway, instead of growing text elements to absurdly large sizes, I'd choose a different layout, and simply not let the control occupy the entire window.

Comment: @Clemens `The whole control in a single Viewbox` - That MIGHT be exactly what I need. I'll try that. But everything I've read says "Use Viewboxes". It may be that I've just been going about it wrong. I'll try to put my ItemControl into a single viewbox.